# How to handle unwarranted downvotes

Tags: discussion, downvotes, deleted-answers, answer-quality

**TL;DR** is there any way to handle unjustified downvotes to quality answers, other than deleting and reposting a more elaborate answer?

---

I have a question which I answered to the best of my ability. Doing so I provided examples and pertinent links to resources explaining the reason for the answer.

A user suggested an edit which clearly conflicted with my posts intent, so I rejected it. Additionally, I provided a polite reason as to why I rejected it.

In turn, the answer was met with a downvote from the user and a comment that my example was incorrect. I elaborated as to why this was not the case with my answer and even went as far as creating a working example on github.

Comment: You move on. (The user who commented on that post you linked to has cast zero downvotes, per his profile.)

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't that user, or maybe it was since their downvotes have updated to two. But it was welcomed with a downvote twice. Once for the slightly less elaborate answer that was to the point that I deleted. And second being latest answer. Oh well...

Comment: The second downvote very well might have been because you *deleted an answer and reposted it because of a single downvote.* This is downright childish.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I reposted it with 2x more of an explanation as the first, hoping that it was justified enough to warrant its deletion and submission of a mostly different answer. I didn't particularly consider it being childish. Just wanted to preserve the reputation for it being a *valid answer*. As Oxinabox pointed out, It kind hurts more than it should though to get unfair downvotes.

Comment: You deleted it and reposted it because of the downvote. If you wanted to expand on your answer, you could have just edited the original like everyone else.

Comment: Understood... I can se how doing so would have provoked another downvote now. I have deleted previous answers which I hastily posted without fully understanding the question's criteria and been subsequently downvoted (I feel that's not so uncommon). I only deleted this post because I felt it could be distracting future answer-seekers from the factual one provided.

Comment: Next time I'll do what you mentioned and wait it out.

Comment: Note that you've answered question that is very likely different from what OP is actually looking for (root-relative path are as useless to zip verision of the site like absolute once)... So I'd personally downvote such answer if I see it directly and not from META post.

Comment: @Seth I have rolled back the last edit you made to your question. As it fundamentally changes the question. "Blatently" and  "Seemingly" are near opposites.

Comment: I dunno.  If I got a single downvote like that, I'd be a wreck.  I'd cover myself in wine boxes and haagen-dazs chocolate ice cream, crawl into a blanket fort and cry a river so deep and wide it'd carve out a new grand canyon stretching from my basement to the atlantic ocean.  Then I'd rent donkeys to tourists.

Comment: The criticism in the comments looks to be correct.  So, I would consider the downvote *justified*, at least in the sense of how you're *supposed* to use downvotes.  User offered a correction (not the edit, just a comment), you chose to ignore it and then you got a downvote.  Pretty common series of events I think.  Then you whined about it and got more downvotes in response.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Stand up. Take a deep breath, and walk away.
We're only talking about imaginary internet points.

If you have trouble letting go (I know I do), you might want to consider blocking the site until you've forgotten about it.

[image: XKCD I cna't go to bed someone is wrong on the internet]
Obligatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/386/)

Downvotes are an exercise of free will. You pay 1 rep to take 2 rep from someone else. They (unlike close votes) don't have to follow any criteria. Other than not being revenge/serial downvotes (which you can still make, but the system will generally revert). The reasons shown in the tool tip are just guidelines. Which by freewill can be ignored.

It kinda hurts more than it should though to get unfair downvotes, I know.
It also hurts to give feedback the other person just doesn't understand.

Comment: You forgot to mention that one down vote on a post that has at least one upvote still gives you a positive net rep increase. It all comes out in the wash

Comment: @Matt yeah I did. I thought of mentioining that, but I didn't since this answer  does have (at time of writing) net negitive score, which makes it unclear as to if it has any upvotes (I didn't check)

Comment: The solution to someone pointing out a potential problem with an answer of yours isn't to learn to ignore them and pretend that you've done nothing wrong.  To refuse to ever accept constructive feedback is extremely harmful and will prevent you from improving, and result in you continuing to propagate problematic content to others.

Comment: @Servy I agree, completely. Note my last sentence: *"It also hurts to give feedback the other person just doesn't understand."*  .  But when they are downvoting you and you can't work out why and can't aplease them, then there is nothing else to do. Note that the Question title was **"How to handle *blatantly* unjustified downvotes"** when I wrote this answer

Comment: @Oxinabox To take it as an assumption that a downvote is "blatantly unjustified" rather than taking it as valuable feedback you can use to improve your answer is exactly the problem.

Comment: Sure. I don't disagree. But at the end of the day, there is limits to your ability to comprehend the meanings of others. Particularly since almost noone here is being paid for it. So if you can't get the meaning, and can't work out what to improve, that is when my answer applies. You sound like you have strong and well developed opinions. Go write your own answer. Then you can express them fully.